# Laravel Call to a member function first() on null

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm using VueJS and Laravel for an application I'm developing. I've tried to search here for an answer, but I haven't found anything that works. Most of the times, it's because there's really nothing to return, but I've tried to debug my query quite a bit, and I don't understand why I keep getting a null.

So I'm trying to get information about the student who's logged in, so I'm doing an axios get on a route that executes the following:

```
public function getByUserId($id) {
    //$student = $this->studentRepo->findByUserId($id);
    $student = Student::where('user_id', $id)->first();
    $inscription = Inscription::where('student_id', $student->id)->first();
    $student->careers;

    $res = $inscription ? new InscriptionResource($inscription) : '';

    return response()->json([
        'student' => new StudentResource($student),
        'inscription' => $res,
    ]);
}
```

The thing is, it doesn't find the student with that user_id. I've checked if the user_id (param: $id) is getting there as expected and it is. I've also tried to get the query via ->toSql() and copy pasted the query on the database to test it and I do get the student I'm trying to search for. Thing is, it's not finding it in Laravel for some reason, I'm not sure why.

My student table does have the attribute "user_id", I've checked.

Student file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Student extends Model {
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function charges() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Payment');
    }
}
```

Comment: Syntax appears to be correct. At which exact line do you receive the error?

Comment: @user8555937 at the third line "$student = Student::where('user_id', $id)->first();" I keep getting "Call to a member function first() on null". And as I mentioned, I executed the query manually and it works, not in Laravel though.

Comment: Are you sure `Student` is an Eloquent model? Please post its code if you can

Comment: @user8555937 I edited my original post with the code, I didn't create that file, and my knowledge of models is very limited, but it seems to be one. What's weird is that I've done that same exact query on another function, and it works as it should.

Comment: Try `Student::select('*')->where('user_id', $id)->first();` instead. What Laravel version do you have?

Comment: Could it be possible that the user you are searching for has been soft deleted?

Comment: @user8555937 tried it right now, still the same. I'm using laravel 6.17.1

Comment: @ingkevin no, it doesn't seem to be that way. I've tried with a freshly created user, and with another user, and I keep getting the same output.

Comment: Double check that you're pointed to the right Student class. Is there a `use App\Models\Student;` in the file that contains the method `getByUserId()`? Otherwise, maybe try the full namespace `App\Models\Student::where()`?

Comment: @Spudly yep, I'm using App\Models\Student on my Controller. What's weird to me is that on another function, I used the EXACT same query, and it works fine, but in getByUserId(), I keep getting that error.

Comment: Have you tried to use a DB raw query? `DB::select('select * from students where id = :id', ['id' => $id]);`?

Comment: Does `Student::all()` return any results?

Comment: @RodrigoZea, that's strange. If the error is `first() on null`, then that's different than first() returning null. Usually that error means the class isn't configured right or something is wrong with how it's being called. Are you instantiating or injecting any other classes that might conflict with Student? I'm not sure why the query would work in the other method in the same file, but I don't see any issues with the code here. How large is the file that contains `getByUserId`? Is that something you can post?

Comment: @ingkevin tried that right now, didn't work, got "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object" on $inscription.

Comment: @Spudly I could upload it somewhere else maybe? It's not too big anyways.

Comment: Stupid question but: could it be possible that your student is soft-deleted?

Comment: That error seems to be from line $student->id rather than the query. Can you debug to see the result of the raw query?

Comment: @RodrigoZea If the original error is `first() on null`, it seems like this is a class issue. Did you try `App\Models\Student::where()->first()`? If that works, try posting the construct method with all the imported classes and the other method with the query that works. Just FYI and you might already know this, but `DB::select()` query returns multiple results unless first() is called on that or you loop through the results. I think that would explain a `non-object` error if you put that query into `$student` and then call `$student->id` immediately after.

Comment: @ingkevin could be, I commented the $inscription line, and it seems like it's not saying the same thing anymore. But still, I don't know why it'd say that, I have a similar code on another program that gets information from the student but with their student code rather than with their user id in the database and it works fine. Also not sure again, since $student seems to print empty all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Add the related column in the relation function

```
public function charges() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Payment', '');
    }
```